# MYSQL join without using primary key

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I wonder if MYSQL can do something as follow:

```
 **Table 1**
    |name|salary|seniorLevel|
    |Angela|3500||
    |Cindy|4500||
    |Sam|||
    |Paul|8000||


    **Table2**
    |seniorLevel|salary_start|salary_end|
    |A|3001|4000|
    |B|4001|5000|
    |C|5001|6000|

Desired output:
    |Name|salary|seniorLevel|
    |Angela|3500|A|
    |Cindy|4500|B|
    |Sam|||
    |Paul|8000||
```

I managed to get the first two lines desired output (Angela & Cindy) using SQL below, but how can i twist my codes to outputting full set (including Sam & Paul) even they not meet criteria.

```
select Table1.name, Table1.salary, Table2.seniorLevel from Table1, Table2 where Table1.salary <= Table2.end and Table1.salary >= Table2.start;
```

Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 3):

I think you want a `left join`:

```
select t1.*, t2.seniorLevel
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t1.salary >= t2.salary_start and t1.salary <= t2.salary_end;
```

Comment: Woahhhhh.... This looks sweet and precise!! Now i know we can place condition in "ON" function. Thanks Gordon, my savior! I've been struggled the whole night to think on how to tackle this. :)